# How to discard all InputMap key bindings for JSpinner?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, jspinner

My Netbeans RCP application has a global key binding on the SPACE key which triggers action MyAction. It works fine.

My app contains an editable JSpinner. If user presses SPACE while he's editing the spinner value, it also triggers MyAction, and I don't want that.

I found a workaround with:

```
mySpinner.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "doNothing");
mySpinner.getActionMap().put("doNothing", new DoNothingAction());
```

But I will have other global key bindings in my app...

Is there a generic way to remove all key bindings in the JSpinner, without replicating the above code for each new key ?

Answer (score 0):

Both `InputMap` and `ActionMap` have `clear()` methods that remove all existing bindings. You might not want to clear all the bindings though, because they include most probably arrow keys also which are used to select next previous values in spinner.

Comment: clear() does not help here: if InputMap is empty, key bindings are searched up the containment hierarchy. This is why MyAction gets called if I don't add the code shown above.